Can a central device activtate a sleeping peripheral device?
The central device connects with the peripheral device and the peripheral enters into sleep state post the connection,so ideally my question is there any possibility where the central can trigger an event that puts in the peripheral back into active state ?
For e.g My BLE RCU is connected to a TV via BLE ,I operate the RCU and post sometime my RCU is in a sleeping state,Can there be a possible event that could be gerenated from the TV to activate my RCU ?
General question about BLE characteristics

Depends on what you understand as sleep. If the device turned off all BLE communication there is nothing that can be done via BLE. Power saving BLE devices can turn on in regular intervals, e.g. every 60s, to wait for instructions for a certein amount before going to sleep again. But that would need to be implemented on the peripheral

This is really application or profile dependent. Nothing in the BLE core standard itself mentions anything about sleep vs active in this manner.

Thankyou @MichaelKotzjan for the response .. I didn't understand this statement "every 60s, to wait for instructions for a certein amount before going to sleep again",does it mean that 60s its in sleep and post that for 1 second its in active state and again repeat the same cycle ?
Device turned off means deactivation of the Bluetooth right ? Here the BLE is not deactivated its in sleep mode so in that case why can't there be a situation that tthe central activates the peripheral

Hi @Emil it would be great if you elaborate your answer

You need to clarify what you mean with "sleeping state". Please note that BLE devices typically "sleep" between connection events. I'm not sure if it's that you mean or something else.

@ShilpaSR I agree with Emil, you need to clarify what you mean with "sleep". What I was referring to in my previous comment: Usually the BLE module is one if the components that needs the most amount of power. So turning it off when not needed is a valid option. You can turn it on again e.g. every 60 seconds to see if someone wants to communicate. If not, turn it off again. That's what I understand as sleep. And in that case nothin BLE related can turn your device back on

Yes I mean't the same @MichaelKotzjan ,during this 60 seconds interval,if the master wants,Can it activate the slave ?

@ShilpaSR no, there is no way to activate a device via BLE when BLE is deactivated
